# HTML camera captured image auto saved to the mobile phone

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, angularjs

I have a web app and I am using the HTML input to capture the images. But the issue is that it saved every images to the local gallery/Photos in the mobile device.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<input type="file" custom-on-change="uploadFileDeviceCamera" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" capture="environment"/>
```

**Is there any way to prevent the images to be saved to local?**

**OR is there any way to delete the photos from local gallery?**

*I am using ASP .Net Framework and AngularJS.*

Thanks!

Comment: How are you saving them? An example would help.

Comment: @Jimenemex Thanks for the quick reply! I have added my code. I am actually do not know how the mobile saved the images. It saved the image automatically. All I saw was a popup window with a delete button and a OK button. By clicking the OK button the image will be saved behind my program.

Comment: Is this web app running on your mobile device or on a server? What does the code looks like that handles the submitted form data (the .NET code)?